# Extending axis with Google Charts

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

**My question**
I am trying to extend the Y-axis so it is counting to 300 instead of 100.
The problem is that when I change the Y-axis to count to 300, the values are staying on the same place as when it is counting to 100.
So for example if the value on X2 is 10, then it will be displayed as 10 if my Y-axis is counting to 100. But if it is counting to 300, it will be displayed as 30.

Hopefully the problem is clearly described. If you have any questions, feel free to ask them.

**My code**
`<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=x,y&chs=440x220&cht=lxy&chco=3072F3,FF0000&chd=t:0,1,2,4,5,6,7,20|10,20,300,250,150,70,90,40|1,5,9|50,60,70&chdl=Unique Players|Average playtime&chdlp=b&chg=5,60,0,29&chls=2,4,1|1&chma=5,5,10,25&chxr=0,0,100|1,0,300" width="440" height="220" alt="" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that it didn't work because I forgot to set the `chds` parameter.

**chds**

A set of one or more minimum and maximum permitted values for each data series, separated by commas.